# Keras Not Modeling All Rows

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, google-colaboratory

Brand new to Keras, Tensorflow, and Google Colab. I'm following a YouTube tutorial. I have a df with 4000 rows that looks like this:

```
           x            y      color
0       1.752690    2.846610    0.0
1       0.848488    2.127556    0.0
2       2.294166    0.801233    1.0
3       4.137304    3.082904    1.0
4       2.877251    1.915737    1.0
...     ...         ...         ...
3995    4.138087    5.111319    0.0
3996    0.840928    1.691174    0.0
3997    2.820071    3.812626    0.0
3998    3.313544    4.869823    0.0
3999    3.877675    2.553817    1.0
```

Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.read_csv('train.csv')
np.random.shuffle(df.values)

model = keras.Sequential([
  keras.layers.Dense(4, input_shape=(2,), activation='relu'),
  keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(df.loc[:,'x':'y'].values, df.color.values, batch_size=16)
```

Here is the output:

```
250/250 [==============================] - 0s 872us/step - loss: 0.8335 - accuracy: 0.2380
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7fed96a646a0>
```

I'm concerned that the output implies it only ran 250 rows. The ouput as shown in the youtube video has a few rows and in the bottom row says 4000/4000 and then below that says [Finished in 4.5s]. You can see the output by going to 29:13 in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aBIGJeHRZLQ.

Is my model only running 250 rows? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data shown is not the rows. It is the number of batches processed. In model.fit you did  specified the batch size as 16. Consequently With 4000 rows, 4000/16=250 which is the number of steps it takes in an epoch to process all 4000 rows with a batch size of 16

Answer (score 2):

250 is a number of batches trained 250 * 16 = 4000